# Как найти причину долгого запуска приложения

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, view

После того как я сворачиваю приложение вызывается `onPause` и через неск секунд

```
 surfaceDestroyed
    D/MainThread: Game loop executed 3314 times
    D/Menu: onSaveInstanceState
    D/Menu: Stopping...
```

а за эти секунды в свернутое приложение продолжает работать, игровой цикл в доп.потоке запущен. Неужели он всё это время пытается остановить поток ? На эмуляторе всё происходит моментально. 
ДАлее я разворачиваю игру вызывается без задержек

```
 onRestart
D/Menu: onStart
D/Menu: onResume 
D/MainThread: surfaceCreated
D/MainThread: surfaceChanged
D/MainThread: Starting game loop
```

На экране висит последний кадр при котором был поток остановлен , слышны звуки из игры, поток работает, игровой цикл крутится, через неск секунд черный экран, по звуку видно всё продолжает работать и только потом одновременно с появлением в логе строки `I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3e491adf time:279057271`
всё начинает отображаться.

так же сообщения из лога :  `Skipped 1804 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`  что то виснет в главном потоке..но там ничего нет. (и снова повторяю на эмуляторе всё нормально). и так же лог

```
 :I/art: Thread[7,tid=6517,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x557106fc10,peer=0x22c070a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

сейчас пытаюсь найти файл traces.txt  но кажись его без рута не прочитать..в система не могу вообще найти его

почему на эмуляторе лог такой и всё работает как надо.

```
D/Menu: onPause
D/Menu: onSaveInstanceState
D/Menu: Stopping...
D/MainThread: surfaceDestroyed
```

А на телефоне

```
D/Menu: onPause   (тут иногда немножко подвисает, игра свернута но поток работает, иногда подвисает на долго)
D/MainThread: surfaceDestroyed
D/Menu: onSaveInstanceState
D/Menu: Stopping...
```

ЕЩе на что я обратил внимание: onPause выполняется быстро, так как в лог это   D/Menu: onPause   выводится после выполнения.

```
public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        long tickCount= 0L;
        long beginTime;// время начала цикла
        long timeDiff;// время выполнения шага цикла
        int sleepTime;// сколько мс можно спать (<0 если выполнение опаздывает)
        int framesSkipped;// число кадров у которых не выполнялась операция вывода графики на экран
        sleepTime=0;
        long x, x1;
        while(running){
            tickCount++;
            canvas  = null;
            // пытаемся заблокировать canvas
            // для изменение картинки на поверхности
            try{
                this.time.onTickUpdate();
                canvas= this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                  if (canvas == null)
                    continue;

                synchronized(surfaceHolder){
                    beginTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    framesSkipped=0;// обнуляем счетчик пропущенных кадров
                    this.gamePanel.update();// формируем новый кадр    
                    this.gamePanel.Draw(canvas);//Рисуем
                    // вычисляем время, которое прошло с момента запуска цикла
                    timeDiff=System.currentTimeMillis()- beginTime;

                    sleepTime=(int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff); // вычисляем время, которое можно спать

                    if(sleepTime>0){ // если sleepTime > 0 все хорошо, мы идем с опережением
                        try {
                            // отправляем поток в сон на период sleepTime
                             Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException e){}
                    }
                    while(sleepTime<0 && framesSkipped< MAX_FRAME_SKIPS){
                        this.gamePanel.update();
                        sleepTime+= FRAME_PERIOD;
                        framesSkipped++;

                    }
                }
            }
                finally{
                // в случае ошибки, плоскость не перешла в
                //требуемое состояние
                if(canvas!=null){
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            x = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
            x1 = 1000/x;
            System.out.println("FPS= " + x1);
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"Game loop executed "+ tickCount+" times");
    }
```

Comment: Пройдитесь отладчиком между выводами `surfaceDestroyed` и `D/Menu: onSaveInstanceState`.

Comment: Как вариант попробуй отключить Instant Run - из-за этого у меня были тормоза при запуске приложении.

Comment: отключил Instant Run, удалил приложение с телефона, запустил заново. не помогло

Comment: ну попробовал я отладчиком пройтись, ничего не понимаю в выданных данных. только написано местами в коде что исходный код не соответствует байт коду.. погуглил по этому вопросу, вопрос открытый и два вариант очистить проект и отключить инстант ран и то и другое сделал , проблема осталась. Сама Ide а именно андроид студио много кода показывает красным, вот тут я уже задавал вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208242/turalllb?tab=questions&sort=votes    Но ответа не получил, вроде компилируется и гугле ничего дельного.

Comment: И почему вы говорите проверить отладчиком именно между surfaceDestroyed и  onSaveInstanceState ? из каких соображений. я только понимаю что поток дополнительный запускается, а вот основной тормозит. после onPause  долго не вызывается surfaceDestroyed . хотя на эмуляторе порядок вызова иной. Сперва onPause onSaveInstanceState
D/Menu: Stopping...

Comment: и потом только surfaceDestroyed и всё работает прекрасно. а на телефоне после паузы с задержкой дестрой вызывается

Comment: Так а что делают потоки? Может блокируют друг друга по данным?

Comment: мм,.как предлагаете увидеть что они делают ? я вот запустил дебагер , понять ничего особо не смог, но нажав сбоку на Thread reports получил вот что  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608566 . Заметил что подобные репорты есть не только в моем приложении над которым работаю но и в любом другом которые я делаю с подобной архитектурой как здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/246817/    . Не важно на телефоне на котором всё виснет запускаю или на эмуляторе ошибки есть.  Это примитивная архитектура для простых игр и много где она описана, но что то не работает как надо.

Comment: написано например 3 похожих потока . читаю внутри  Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended   т.е. несовместимые состояния потока, поток не приостановлен. я решил запустить приложение и не сворачивая сразу же нажал кнопку НАзад чем вызвал дестрой приложения. Должен был запуститься главный поток и дополнительный в котором шла отрисовка. но в репорте написано о трех потоках

Comment: попробовал много раз сворачивать и разворачивать приложение. при этом поток должен уничтожаться и создаваться новый . но в репорте всё равно написано про три потока. Может это и не имеет даже отношения к делу..Когда потоку подается сигнал чтобы он уничтожился, он ведь не сразу это делает, может это и есть ошибки которые появляются в момент когда поток еще не уничтожен..

Comment: В общем я приблизился к решению проблемы. В игре у меня не было ограничения по FPS. мой телефон успевал нарисовать 100 кадров легко. я Приложил к вопросу Код в котором отрисовка выполняется, обратите внимание на то как КАнвас блокируется и разблокируется. т.е. при дебаге я увидел что после того как канвас разблокируется, тогда и появится нарисованное в OnDraw изображение.  БЫло так: я сворачиваю игру , пауза сразу вызвалась, а surfaceDestroyed пока вызовется успевало еще сотню кадров отрисоваться. теперь выставив фпс 30 , поток работу начал прекращать куда быстрее.

Comment: ну на эмуляторе он еще быстрее прекращает. РЕшил проверить максимальную фпс эмулятора. от 15 до 25 скачет. поставил себе 20 Фпс  и у меня так же моментально всё сворачивается и главное разворачивается. НЕт больше такого что игра развернулась и вижу зависший последний кадр , Поток во всю работает и рисует, но ничего не отображается ,потом черный экран и если повезет экран снова начнет показывать игру. ВОт вопрос , почему всё таки это происходит, как частая перерисовка влияет на то что канвас заблокирован..я в 1.25ночи уже не соображаю

Comment: Я вот хочу чтобы при 60 кадрах не было этих проблем, поэтому надо разобраться как блокировка канваса и высокое число кадров на это повлияли

Comment: И еще одна проблемка остается : при первом запуске игра уже пошла,  но экран еще секунды 3 белый и после того как в логе появится эта строка I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2b711cde time:151464540    появляется картинка . Почему?