# threads_report что могут значить эти ошибки?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-studio

```
    "main@4348" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at example.myapplication999.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:54)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6766)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java:-1)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

"FinalizerDaemon@4400" daemon prio=5 tid=0x9b nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks FinalizerDaemon@4400
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
      - locked <0x1134> (a java.lang.Object)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:204)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@4403" daemon prio=5 tid=0x9c nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@4403
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:269)
      - locked <0x1135> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:249)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon@4401" daemon prio=5 tid=0x9a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks ReferenceQueueDaemon@4401
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:150)
      - locked <0xb9e> (a java.lang.Class)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"HeapTaskDaemon@4399" daemon prio=5 tid=0x9d nid=NA waiting for monitor entry
  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(VMRuntime.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:433)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"Signal Catcher@4397" daemon prio=5 tid=0x98 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder:4052_1@4398" prio=5 tid=0x9e nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder:4052_2@4402" prio=5 tid=0x9f nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Profile Saver@4347" daemon prio=5 tid=0xa0 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended
```

Помогите понять о чем они .

вот скрин https://gyazo.com/36cd45dbfce709aa4478f7765ba12077

там написано например : 5 similiar threads , т.е. 5 похожих потоков ? как я мог успеть столько запустить. Подобные репорты есть во всех приложениях где используется интерфейс SurfaceHolder.Callback и отрисовка выполняется в дополнительном потоке.

Answer (score 1):

Это не ошибки, это дамп потоков JVM (thread dump), который показывает в каком состоянии находился каждый поток и какой конкретно код этим потоком выполнялся.

Полезен при анализе всевозможных зависаний системы, поиска дедлоков, лайвлоков и пр.